# How to mark event in the devtools graph?

Tags: google-chrome, devtools

I want to "mark" a step in performance tab in chrome devtools.

So I use `console.timeStamp` to do so. but this function just add a marker within the graph (as you can see the small rect under the tooltip).

[image]

What I expected to be is create it in the top of the graph.

Something like this (I mark it by red arrow):
This small rect is the `console.timeStamp`, as I want.

So there is a function that mark the way I describe?

[image]